# How to reset bundler path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I've managed to break bundler! I was messing around in a Rails app and I did something like 
`bundle install string`. Now all my gems are being installed into a folder called "string" within the app.

How do I reset bundler to use the default paths for my rvm gemsets?

Another post here suggested using `bundle install --system`, but will this ensure that gems are installed into gemsets?

I have checked `rvm info` and the GEM_HOME and GEM_PATH appear to point to the correct rvm/ gemset directories. So I'm confused as to why gems are not being installed to the correct location.

Sorry if this is a basic question, I'm still trying to understand how all this works. Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need to `rm -rf .bundle` within your app

Comment: thanks, this appears to have worked. I also ran `bundle install --system` and this did not appear to break rvm gem paths.