# Rails: json 1.7.5 bundle install issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json, rubygems, bundler

When running bundle I get the following issue...

> Installing json (1.7.5) with native extensions
>   Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native
>   extension.
>
> ```
>     /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb creating Makefile
> ```
>
> make Makefile:158: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /srv/www/socialu.com/https:/github.com/willfults/rails3-jquery-autocomplete.git/ruby/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.5
>   for inspection. Results logged to
>   /srv/www/socialu.com/https:/github.com/willfults/rails3-jquery-autocomplete.git/ruby/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.5/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
>   An error occured while installing json (1.7.5), and Bundler cannot
>   continue. Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.7.5'` succeeds before
>   bundling.

I tried doing the following `sudo aptitude install ruby1.9.1-dev` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with colons in the makefile...
[Escaping colons in filenames in a Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052406/escaping-colons-in-filenames-in-a-makefile)

Doing this resolved it...
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9952952/1026266

Answer (score 3):

On debian, if ruby installed with apt-get try to install ruby-dev package also

```
#apt-get install ruby-dev
```

it helped in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Try install depedencies:

> sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libreadline5 libreadline5-dev zlib1g zlib1g-dev

Then the usual process

> mkdir ~/src && cd ~/src
>
> wget ftp://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.1-p0.tar.gz
>
> tar -xvf ruby-1.9.1-p0.tar.gz
>
> cd ruby-1.9.1-p0
>
> ./configure
>
> make
>
> make test
>
> sudo make install
>
> And to get rails working properly
>
> sudo gem update --system
>
> sudo gem install rails

and to get sqlite3 working properly

> sudo apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
>
> sudo gem install sqlite3-ruby

Comment: Thanks but this error is still there, also if I run gem install json -v '1.7.5' the gem installs but when I run bundle I get the same error again, very strange.